# Javascript array of canvas objects? Scope issue? ocanvas.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

I'm new to javascript and canvas, but not entirely new to programming (I have some HTML/PHP experience).

I've always had an interest in web games that use grids, so after taking a few javascript courses online, I found some javascript code that dynamically created hexagonal grids of canvas objects.

I've been playing around with the code, adding click events to highlight the hex you're on, trying to put random numbers on the hexes to depict numbers of "units" etc. Sort of mocking up what a game might look like, just for the learning experience.

One thing that I've been trying to do, and I can't seem to figure out, is how to define canvas objects in an array, so that I can reference them by row/column. It seems like it would be much easier, in the context of a game, to reference a grid cell by row/column so that you can do actions based on that location.

I'm using ocanvas.js to create canvas objects, so ideally I'd love to be able to define a grid cell as:

```
hex[row][col] = canvas.display.polygon({
    x: x0,
    y: y0,
    sides: 6,
    radius: this.radius,
    rotation: 0,
    fill: fillColor,
    stroke: "outside 1px #000",
    row: row,
    col: col,
    zIndex: "back",
    selected: false
});
hex[row][col].add();
```

However, I've noticed that mutlidimensional arrays don't work in javascript like they do in PHP.   In PHP, you don't have to predefine the scope of an array.  You can just do:

```
$array = [];
$array[1][5] = "foo";
```

And it'll put that value in the [1][5] position.   In my hex code here: http://tny.cz/14282e49  about 3/4 down I have a comment showing that I want to call my hex[col][row] object... but I'm always getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined" errors, where '5' is the column its trying to access.

So, this is a 2 part question:
1) Am I not defining my `hex` array correctly to access the canvas objects like that?
2) Is there a better way that I'm just not seeing, to access specific canvas objects in a column/row grid format?

Comment: It looks like you redefine `hex` as a new variable.

Comment: you made a mistake in your 'you can just do' : try and you'll see it fails. What works is arr=[]; arr[1]=[]; arr[1][5]='foo'; You have to create an array for all dimension values. That's the same mistake you did in your code.

Comment: Matt R: Damn, that was part of the problem. Joe's answer below did help, but I was redefining 'hex' as a variable in the middle of the code during an event binding function.  Both of those combined, and I now seem to have working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part I:

Before assigning a value to `hex[row][col]`, you need to make sure that `hex[row]` exists.

```
hex[row] = hex[row] || [];
hex[row][col] = canvas.display.polygon({
    x: x0,
    y: y0,
    sides: 6,
    radius: this.radius,
    rotation: 0,
    fill: fillColor,
    stroke: "outside 1px #000",
    row: row,
    col: col,
    zIndex: "back",
    selected: false
});
hex[row][col].add();
```

The line `hex[row] = hex[row] || [];` says "if hex[row] exists, use it. otherwise create a new array. Assign the result to hex[row]."
The `||` "or" operator is used as a "default" here. See this page as a reference: http://seanmonstar.com/post/707078771/guard-and-default-operators

---

Part II:

http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#coordinates

I recommend using the "axial coordinate" system used at that resource. Read the entire thing. It's a long post and is way too much information for a SO answer here.

Comment: Hmm, I've never seen that sort of declaration (hex[row] = hex[row] || [];

I tried it, and I still get the same exception.

Also, I've definitely read Amit's hexagon paper. Great stuff in there about the math of it all, but still trying to learn about the javascript.

Comment: Is `row` or `col` >= 30?

Comment: According to the code in the OP, row or col should never be higher than 25, as shown in this function call:  

      hexagonGrid.drawHexGrid(15, 25, 25, 25, true);

So, the ones I'm click on and getting that error are definitely <= 25

Comment: @bo_knows : >> never seen that sort of declaration hex[row] = hex[row] || []; << that just proves a lack of practice. The || operator is commonly used in js to easily select a non-null object. Joe is right about the way to go, dig a bit more.

Comment: Part of the reason it wasn't working is that I was redefining 'hex' as a variable later, as part of a click event.  It was botching up the hex array.  Everything seems to be working!